# 15-second comment timer counterproductive

Tags: feature-request, comments, usability

I just came back to a question of mine and tried to type two short comments on the two helpful responses. I had a bad user experience, from my perspective, when I could not type the second one in because 15 seconds had not passed.

Comment: It's already a feature. Oh, wait, do you want to *remove* the feature? Ah, magic 8 ball says [status-declined].

Comment: It is truly the worst bug (by design) in Stack Overflow.  The timer resets every time it happens.

Comment: But it warns you in its own cryptic way

Comment: If you can type two responses within 15 seconds, do you really think those responses are "productive"?

Comment: @raven, I figured that was the counter to my request - in this case it was basically to give a little appreciation to the answer that was not really better or worse than the one I checked.  I assume the whole thing is in the prevention of spam bots, and the low timeout makes using captcha irrelivant..

Comment: It's not the 15 seconds that is aggravating, it is the timer reset if you retry in 14.5 seconds instead of 15. (one thousand one, one thousand two, one thousand three...)

Comment: I agree with both Roberts here, it's more useful than harmful and should stay. 15 seconds are really not that long.

Comment: Should be 10 seconds not 15....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The misuse of comments starts with users who post endless "me too", "I agree", and other such banal chit-chat. Having said that, if you really *did* post two consecutive, *useful* comments in 15 seconds, that is an unusual *edge* case.

Stack Exchange is a wide-open and largely anonymous public forum. As such, one of our best defense against wide-spread misuse, spam, and overt vandalism is to throttle *EVERY* activity users can perform to a reasonable, human level.

I believe that any possible inconvenience you experienced by having to wait a few extra seconds to post another comment **is trumped by the damage that someone could cause** if they raced through the system posting:

F YOU GUYS! – [Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino)♦ 15 seconds ago 
You  – [Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino)♦ 15 seconds ago 
moved  – [Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino)♦ 15 seconds ago 
my  – [Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino)♦ 15 seconds ago 
cheese  – [Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino)♦ 15 seconds ago 
so  – [Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino)♦ 14 seconds ago 
I'm  – [Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino)♦ 14 seconds ago 
taking  – [Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino)♦ 14 seconds ago 
my  – [Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino)♦ 14 seconds ago 
ball  – [Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino)♦ 13 seconds ago 
and  – [Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino)♦ 13 seconds ago 
going – [Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino)♦ 13 seconds ago
home – [Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino)♦ 12 seconds ago
you – [Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino)♦ 12 seconds ago
butt-monkey – [Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino)♦ 12 seconds ago
scum – [Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino)♦ 11 seconds ago
laterz – [Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino)♦ 11 seconds ago
lamerz – [Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino)♦ 10 seconds ago
OMG – [Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino)♦ 10 seconds ago
u  – [Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino)♦ 10 seconds 
n00b  – [Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino)♦ 10 seconds 
STFU  – [Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino)♦ 9 seconds 
u 
d1dn7 – [Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino)♦ 9 seconds 
qu0t3 – [Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino)♦ 9 seconds 
|\|um4– [Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino)♦ 9 seconds 
 
|\|um4 – [Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino)♦ 9 seconds 
|21t3 – [Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino)♦ 9 seconds 
OMG – [Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino)♦ 9 seconds 
FU!!1" – [Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino)♦ 9 seconds 
ciao – [Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino)♦ 8 seconds ago
n00b – [Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino)♦ 8 seconds ago
suxzorz – [Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino)♦ 7 seconds ago
1 rulez!!!!!11!!!1 – [Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino)♦ 7 seconds ago

Comment: It's hard to argue with such an eloquent illustration.

Comment: Yea, but other throttles are relaxed based on rep.

Comment: I almost never hit the 15 second timer. But when I do, I'm usually _very_ upset about not being to guess 15 seconds very well. Several times.

Comment: @sarnold the first time I trip it I changeup and count to 20 next time. If I don't get it then I leave the comment in the tab and open reddit. By then 15 seconds are usually gone ;)

Comment: @jcolebrand, ah, you've got a second addiction. That must help.

Comment: @sarnold it does at times ;)

Comment: some of us are touch typists, I get zinged by this all the time.

Comment: wow you got tool to generate those things? ;)

Comment: That tirade represents the equivalent of 44 words in 8 seconds, or 330 words per minute.  That's pretty impressive, Robert!