# Could someone clarify the comment: `Yea, but other throttles are relaxed based on rep`

Tags: support, reputation, privileges, rate-limiting

In [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96775), @Rosinante posted the comment almost at the very bottom:

`Yea, but other throttles are relaxed based on rep`

Is this true?  Do the timers, etc. go away with higher rep?  This would be nice.

Comment: FYI - the one that bugs me is the 5-second timer on comment up-votes.  Often, when reading a post, clarification comments come in pairs and I'd like to have enough rep someday to avoid this limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the timers go away, I assume Rosinante had other features in mind.

[Here is the list of privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges) that can be gained with reputation

(I still have the 5 second timer on comment upvotes with more than 3000 rep on SO)

Comment: I'm definitely familiar with the [rep page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges).  I just had a suspicion that there were also unspoken/uncited privileges awarded.

Comment: @M. Tibbits I haven't got any unspoken/uncited privileges, yet (or at least I am not aware of). But maybe I had need just more rep for those ;).